# iOS : Get substring from a html tag response

Tags: ios, substring

In my program I'm getting an html notification tag use

```
   "<script>p(34,'1','hello world');</script>/r/n"
```

I need now is to get the string "hello world" from above tag and it should be a dynamic process as the length of text varies for every response tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this one.... I Hope this work will fine..

```
NSString *data = @"<script>p(34,'1','hello world');</script>/r/n";

    NSRange divRange = [data rangeOfString:@"','" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (divRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange endDivRange;

        endDivRange.location = divRange.length + divRange.location;
        endDivRange.length   = [data length] - endDivRange.location;
        endDivRange = [data rangeOfString:@"'" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:endDivRange];

        if (endDivRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            divRange.location += divRange.length;
            divRange.length  = endDivRange.location - divRange.location;

            NSLog(@"SubString  %@",[data substringWithRange:divRange]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work. You may have to adjust the fromString and toString if those parts of the message are also dynamic, but this will get you started.

```
NSString *someString = @"<script>p(34,'1','hello world');</script>/r/n";

NSString *fromString = @"<script>p(34,'1','";
NSRange fromRange = [someString rangeOfString:fromString];

NSString *toString = @"');</script>/r/n";
NSRange toRange = [someString rangeOfString:toString];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(fromRange.location + fromRange.length, toRange.location - (fromRange.location + fromRange.length));
NSString *result = [someString substringWithRange:range];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * myString = @"<script>p(34,'1','hello world');</script>/r/n";//@" hello(1234)";
NSRange range1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange range2 = [myString rangeOfString:@"'" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

if ((range1.length == 1) && (range2.length == 1) && (range2.location > range1.location))
{
    NSRange range3;
    range3.location = range1.location+2;
    range3.length = (range2.location - range1.location)-2;
    NSString *subString  = [myString substringWithRange:range3];
    NSLog(@"%@",subString)
}
```

**outPut----> hello world**